# Rewrite rule for name.123456.js in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have this file in my webserver:

```
http://example.com/static/js/min/common.min.js
```

Since all files inside `/static/` are cached with CloudFlare's Edge Cache, I need a way to change the url with something like this, so if the file is modified, the new version will be automatically fresh served:

```
http://example.com/static/js/min/common.min.1234567890.js
```

Where 1234567890 is the timestamp of the file's date modification. I already generate the filename according to the modification date, the issue I'm having is in the .htaccess file.

This works fine:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.[\d]{10}\.(js)$ $1.$2 [L]
```

That means that:

```
http://example.com/static/js/min/common.min.1234567890.js
```

Is redirected to:

```
http://example.com/static/js/min/common.min.js
```

But, that will catch all .js requests from the domain, I just want to catch .js requests from within /static/js/min/*.js -- but this is failing:

```
RewriteRule ^static/js/min/(.*)\.[\d]{10}\.(js)$ $1.$2 [L]
```

What should the rule be like?

Comment: Please check the answer and let me know whether you face any issue or not.

Comment: 1. where the .htaccess lays. 2. are there any related `RewriteRule`s in another configs.

Comment: place the .htaccess with `RewriteRule ^common\.min\.\d+\.js$ common.min.js [L]` to static/js/min

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your question,

You want to redirect

```
http://example.com/static/js/min/common.min.1234567890.js
```

to

```
http://example.com/static/js/min/common.min.js
```

### So, How to do that

#### the .htaccess

First add

```
 RewriteEngine On
```

To turn on the rewrite engine

#### Then the next important line comes

```
RewriteRule ^static/js/min/([^\d]*)(\d{10}).js$ static/js/min/$1js [L]
```

#### Explanation

Set the path as `static/js/min/`

Then we use RegEx to take the string until a non digit. `([^\d]*)`.

That is `common.min.` is captured.

**Now `$1` is `common.min.`**

Then to match the url, we use `(\d{10})` to capture the digits.

That is `1234567890` is captured.

**Now `$2` is `1234567890` which we don't want anymore**

Then redirect to

```
static/js/min/$1js
```

Not that here we didn't added the `.` after the `$1` because `$1` ending with a `.` (`common.min.`)

So, the code will be

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^static/js/min/([^\d]*)(\d{10}).js$ static/js/min/$1js [L]
```

#### Working Screenshot

**My File Structure**

[image]

The Address in Browser

[image]